# How do I find PHP modules that depend on a deprecated library?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, replace, openssl, mcrypt

I have upgraded my AWS-EC2 LAMP configuration to Ubuntu 16.04, Apache/2.4.39, mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.27, PHP 7.1.28, which removes the PHP mcrypt module.  I need to find out if my configuration actually uses mcrypt functionality.  If not, I can safely remove the load requests that are causing errors.  If yes, then I need to find a way to use openssl to replace mcrypt.  I understand that it does not make good sense to force load the mcrypt module, but there doesn't seem to be a ready-made replacement.  Advice?

Comment: I do not think this question is about AWS EC2 it more generally applies to the package manager on debian.

Comment: David, I agree.  The details are added to provide background; they are not part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to find out if my configuration actually uses mcrypt functionality.

`grep -r mcrypt /path/to/your/code` should be sufficient.

> I understand that it does not make good sense to force load the mcrypt module, but there doesn't seem to be a ready-made replacement.

https://github.com/phpseclib/mcrypt_compat can be used as a drop in pure-PHP replacement for mcrypt.

Comment: thank you for the reference.  I will check into it.